# Codeigniter variables from constructor are undefined

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, constructor, global

I'm using CI's Auth Tank library to query records for certain users.

The variable `$user_id = tank_auth->get_user_id();` grabs the user id from the session. I want to pull records where `user_id = $user_id`.

From what I understood, constructors can load variables each time a class is initiated. Sort of like global variables. So I figured I'll set my `$user_id` in a model constructor so I can use it for multiple functions within the model class.

```
class My_model extends Model {

    function My_model() 
    {
        parent::Model();
        $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();     
    }

        function posts_read() //gets db records for the logged in user
    {       
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Next, I'm loading the model, creating an array in my controller, and sending the data to my view where I have a foreach loop.

When testing I get

> Message: Undefined variable: user_id

in my model. It works however if I define the `$user_id` variable in my `posts_read` function, but I don't want to define it in every function that needs it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variable scope problem. You should create class-level variables so that it is available in other functions as well like this:

```php
class My_model extends Model {
    private $user_id = null;

    function My_model() 
    {
        parent::Model();
        $this->user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();     
    }

    // gets db records for the logged in user
    function posts_read()   
    {       
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Notice the addition of `$user_id` after class declaration which is later used with `$this->user_id` :)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work without a class-level var as well. Is that alright?

Comment: function My_model is not a constructor. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555822/codeigniter-controller-constructor

Answer (score 6):

Pull it into global scope

```
class My_model extends Model {

    $user_id = 0;

    function My_model() {
        parent::Model();
        $this->user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();     
    }

    function posts_read() //gets db records for the logged in user {       
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: @CyberJunkie The same as did Safraz with NULL. I initialised it with a real value since no user will have `0` as his id. Both `NULL` and `0` are fine IMO